# AngularJS Select and Radio Buttons Lose Binding After Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I've looked at all the posts I could find about this issue but I don't see what's wrong with my code.

I've created a directive for both select box and radio buttons:

Select:

```
app.directive("selectBox", function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            fieldobj: "="
        },
        template: '<div ng-show="fieldobj.IsRelevant"><span>{{fieldobj.Title}}:  </span>' +
            '<select ng-model="fieldobj.Value" ng-options="option for option in fieldobj.Options"  ng-class="{fieldError : fieldobj.Errors.length > 0}"/></div>'
    };
});
```

Radio buttons:

```
app.directive("radioButton", function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            fieldobj: "="
        },
        template: '<div ng-show="fieldobj.IsRelevant"><span>{{fieldobj.Title}}:  </span>' +
            '<input type="radio" value="true" ng-model="fieldobj.Value" ng-class="{fieldError : fieldobj.Errors.length > 0}"/>Yes' +
            '<input type="radio" value="false" ng-model="fieldobj.Value" ng-class="{fieldError : fieldobj.Errors.length > 0}"/>No</div>'
    };
});
```

My problem is that after I select a value (in either controls) and fire an ajax to the server, when the data returns (and I see in fiddler/chrome debugger that the data returns just fine) the input element is empty, i.e., neither of the radio buttons is selected and the select box has the value 0 (empty selection).

If i'm writing wrong code here and you have a better suggestion that's fine, but I'll also appreciate if someone could explain why the inputs become "empty".

EDIT: This is the html section of the radio button, for example's sake:

`<div radio-button fieldobj="data.GotWebsite"></div>`

Comment: Could you post the code where you are sending ajax events and also the HTML where you are using these directives?

Comment: @rob Posted the HTML part. About the ajax part, I rather not post too much code so this becomes an unappealing question :) I can tell you that I placed a div with the values and I see them correctly on the ajax return, so I know for sure the values return correctly.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to post your controller code too. In your controller, after the server responds, is `data.GotWebsite` getting set to the correct value?

Comment: @sethro Yes, all the data is returned correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

I had to change `value="true"` to `ng-value="true"` on the input elements.

The `JSON` return by the ajax returned `true`/`false` for the radio buttons, and my guess is that the `ng-value="true"` evaluates the expression and therefore fixes the issues.